# Filter list-items on certain words based on HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to filter out list items based on certain words in a string (in this case city names). The list is inside of a foreach loop and contains about 45 list items (i.e. City Name - Some text) which are added via Wordpress.

I have added a `<select>` element before the list containing the city names as options. Is it possible to filter out list items that do not contain the selected value?

I have a filter that works which is based on classes.

```
(function filterContent() {
     var location = document.getElementById("location-select").value;

        if(location=="all") {
          jQuery(".list-item").css("display","block");
      } else {
          jQuery(".list-item."+location).css("display","block");
          jQuery(".list-item:not(."+location+")").css("display","none");
      }
});
```

However I can't individually add specific classes to each list-item since it's inside of a foreach loop so I don't think this is the best solution.

This is an example of how I have the `<select>` element set up:

```
<div class="location-filter">
    <select id="location-select" name="locationselect" 
    onchange="filterContent();">
        <option value="all" selected>All locations</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
        <option value="cityname">City Name</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the list in php:

```
<div class="list">
    <a class="list-item"><?php echo $list-item-text ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: _"I don't think this will work"_...why not? What problem do you foresee? Have you tried it? _"Like this one"_ We can't see it...what do you think is special about it? How short does it have to be before it's "short"? How long does it have to be before it's "long"? We need some more info

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure if adding the current code would be of any help since all I have is a <select> element and a list containing only one item since it's part of a loop and only contains 1 item. Well it might work but I'll somehow have to extract only the City Names from each list item and turn these into classes. I was thinking along the lines of comparing the option values to the list items and see if theres a match.

Comment: @Marrrc Sounds to me like you have a plan. Come back to us if it doesn't work, we're a lot more likely to help you with a specific problem.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR I wasn't really sure where to start as it's still a bit confusing. My question was a bit vague and I admit I posted it on a whim while a bit frustrated. I'll figure something out and if I get stuck I'll be back with a more specific question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem and to not leave an open question I'll leave my solution to filtering content here.

It ended up being quite simple. What this does is simply check if there's any similarity between the option value and each of the list item's content and then only returns items that have matching values. This would also work with text input fields.

Hope this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#location-select").change(function(){
        // Retrieve the option value and reset the count to zero
        var locationSelect = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        $(".list-item").each(function(){
            // If the list item does not match the value remove it from the results
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(locationSelect, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            // Show the list item if the value matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).css("display", "block");
                count++;
            }
        });
        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-select-count").text("Results = "+count);
    });
});
```

```css
.list a.list-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="location-select" name="locationselect">
  <option value="Sidneystad">Sidneystad</option>
  <option value="North Jaedenport">North Jaedenport</option>
  <option value="Lake">Lake</option>
</select>
<span id="filter-select-count"></span>

<div class="list">
  <a href="#" class="list-item">
    Sidneystad - Description
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-item">
    North Jaedenport - Description
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-item">
    Lake Titusville - Description
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-item">
    Lake West - Description
  </a>
</div>
```